# In unordered_multimap, will find() return the first element with the key?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I understand that in the iterator sequence of a `std::unordered_multimap`, equal keys are grouped together. Is `find()` guaranteed to return the first element with the key, or can it return any element with the key? Is the only reliable way to get all elements with the key `equal_range`?

I am wary of `equal_range()` because it has linear complexity on the number of elements with the same key, so if I can do it with `find()` I would save one iteration over the same key elements.

Comment: Is everyone misreading `unordered_multimap` as `multimap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In unordered_multimap, will find() return the first element with the key?

It's not guaranteed.

If we assume each bucket is a linked list of nodes, `find` and `equal_range` are probably doing the same linear scan within the bucket to find the key. That means that `find` probably *does* give the first element.

If an implementation used something more exotic than a linked list for its bucket storage, I guess they might really diverge: say it actually kept a binary tree for each bucket, then `find` might return the highest match in the tree rather than the leftmost one.

I'm not sure if such an implementation exists or would be conformant though.

Comment: The extra iteration I was referring to was to find the last element. `find()` and `equal_range()` might be the same to find the initial iterator, but to find the final, `equal_range()` would have to iterate through all elements of the same key. This is the same operation I will have to perform, so it seems redundant to me.

Comment: Since the iterators are required to be bidirectional, you could always use `find()` and then walk _backwards_ until you find the first element with a different key. Optimistically that loop will usually be a single operation. Obviously the pessimistic case is that `find()` returns the _last_ suitable element, but I guess it's still no worse than `equal_range()`